# Php Prefix Post Change

Tags: php, posts

In my website people can post videos and pictures. All posts are in this format

```
domain.com/gag/02938482
```

How can I change the prefix of a post, instead of `gag` to have `p` for example.

Comment: you can do this via .htaccess

Comment: I have that line but if I change nothing happens: RewriteRule ^gag/(.*) view.php?pid=$1

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what happened/didn't happen, what errors you got, etc. If you put a bit more effort into writing the question people are more likely to put more effort into writing an answer!

Comment: try this `^p/(.*) view.php?pid=$1`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `RewriteEngine on` in the `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on                                 # Turns the rewrite engine on
RewriteRule ^gag/([^/.]+)/?$ view.php?pid=$1 [L]
```

- `^` start of the string to rewrite
- `gag/`
- `(` start of capturing a variable
- `[` start of a character group
- `^/.` anything not equal to / with any character behind it (.)
- `]` end of a character group
- `+` one or more of the character(group)
- `)` end of capturing a variable
- `/?` zero or more slashes
- `$` end of the string to rewrite
- `view.php?pid=` string after rewriting
- `$1` variable 1 (captured with the `()` )
- `[L]` last rule to rewrite

Comment: please read question first before answer. he wants `p` instead of `gag`

Comment: Please read comments below question before commenting: "I have that line but if I change nothing happens: `RewriteRule ^gag/(.*) view.php?pid=$1` – DegX CM Punk"